# update problem phone lock

Tags: insider-preview

In my phone After update windows 10  phone is not working when I on my phone afterenter my pass key  phone say ""your phone is locked for security reasons to connect a power source at least 2hour then restart it"""" but this commend is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "this commend is not working"? Did you try to do what the message says - connect a power source for at least 2 hours, then restart? If so, what happened after the restart? Also, which phone do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://account.microsoft.com/devices on a browser.

Select your phone then lock it it will ask you to use a 6 digit code. The phone will lock and write goodbye.

Restart it and use the code to unlock it and the message will be gone and you will be at your start screen.

Ensure ur phone is connected to the internet during this process.